# NXT (NXC) Programs are too slow

Tags: nxt, programming, nxc

I am using Bricx Command Center to write some NXC code for a side project. I am working with the MindSqualls C# Library in Unity and am trying to figure out some ways to use the NXT robots in an event-driven situation.

Since lots of things change on the fly with event-driven programming I need to be able to run different NXC programs multiple times, and very quickly.

I have a collection of basically three line programs that I need to run about 12 times a second or so.

The problem is, the NXT brick cannot run them fast enough, the NXT brick UI that goes from the file selected to "Done" is seemingly taking up a half of a second per run. Because of this I can only run the program about twice a second.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to disable the UI so it doesn't waste any time or even bypass the Brick firmware all together so I could just interface with the hardware directly, or maybe even rewrite some of the Brick's firmware to make it faster.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Brick Firmware Info:
FW:    1.28
AVR:   1.01
BC4:   1.01
Build: 1902091856

MindSqualls v2.2.0

Comment: Why do you have to have 3 separate programs? Can't you just put all of the code into one NXC program and use messages to trigger the 3 different branches as needed?

Comment: Personally I'd ditch the brick.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that the UI is what is slowing the brick down, it sounds like your program is *very* resource intensive.  If you are looking to stay with the platform, you may wish to consider the [BrickPI](http://www.dexterindustries.com/brickpi/) which is a little pricy (but hey, you have an NXT), and uses a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org) to control the motors and sensors, which may give you the processing boost.